# Python | How to add a string to every row in a csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

I'm am trying to add a "Name" field to every row in a CSV. Currently, I have an array which contains all the values I want to write to CSV.

Field I want to add

```
diskimage_name = "name"

#Creating the Aarry 

arr_gpsbe = [r.split(",") for r in [r for r in text.split("{;}")]]


#arr_gps.be: values to be written

GPS BE:  [['171536396', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2017-03-13T12/1 2/1 45/1', '51.5911', '-0.04806', '20.695', '0', ''], ['186839052', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2017-03-13T12/1 2/1 45/1', '51.5411', '-0.0554806', '20.6495', '0', ''], ['261713932', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2017-03-13T14/1 30/1 55/1', '51.547', '-0.06583', '19.3311', '0', ''], ['472133644', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2018-02-13T12/1 2/1 47/1', '50.7414', '-1.8727', '3.5862', '0', ''], ['614559756', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2018-02-13T12/1 3/1 0/1', '50.746', '-1.88712', '41.017', '0.32', ''], ['1249259520', 'f36baba228d0de8580380832d544d505', '2015-11-01T14/1 19/1 176/100', '51.508', '-0.096389', '26.0428', '0', ''], ['2296086528', '27f762ddb9443616987939a59ad7214d', '2016-08-22T11/1 26/1 10/1', '41.8994', '12.453', '28.0482', '0', ''], ['4045778956', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2017-03-09T12/1 28/1 58/1', '51.411', '-0.03333', '18.3268', '0', ''], ['5446492172', '00000000000000000000000000000000', '2017-05-14T10/1 23/1 2644/100', '50.7371', '-1.289', '3.2384', '0.06631']]

#Csv Writer

 fieldnames = 'Disk Location', 'Hash', 'Date', 'Latitude', 'Longitude', 'Somethingelse', 'other'
        with open("C:\\ProgramData\\gps.csv", 'w', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
            writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
            writer.writerow(fieldnames)
            writer.writerows(arr_gpsbe)
            csvfile.close()
```

I'm trying to get the data to look like this:

```
Disk Name   Disk Location   Hash    Date    Latitude    Longitude   Somethingelse   other
Name    171536396   0   2017-03-13T12/1 2/1 45/1    51.5411 -0.0554806  20.6495 0
Name    186839052   0   2017-03-13T12/1 2/1 45/1    51.5411 -0.0554806  20.6495 0
Name    261713932   0   2017-03-13T14/1 30/1 55/1   51.5407 -0.0606583  19.3311 0
Name    472133644   0   2018-02-13T12/1 2/1 47/1    50.7414 -1.88727    39.5862 0
Name    614559756   0   2018-02-13T12/1 3/1 0/1 50.7416 -1.88712    41.0317 0.32
```

Is it easier to add the 'Disk Name' field to every value to the 'arr_gps' array I.E

```
 arr_gpsbe = diskimage_name.join()[r.split(",") for r in [r for r in text.split("{;}")]]
```

or is it better to add it to a every row using the csvwrtier?

i.e

```
writer.writerows(diskimage_name, arr_gpsbe)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
writer.writerows(diskimage_name, arr_gpsbe)
```

Use:

```
writer.writerows([[diskimage_name, *row] for row in arr_gpsbe])
```

Or, alternatively:

```
for row in arr_gpsbe:
    writer.writerow([diskimage_name, *row])
```

If you want to avoid creating another copy of the entire data set.